# In Flutter, CameraController's speed is only 16 fps

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-learning, google-mlkit, pose-estimation

GOOGLE MLKIT Pose Detection says [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection):

> The base SDK runs in real time on modern phones like the Pixel 4 and iPhone X. It returns results at the rate of ~30 and ~45 fps respectively.

However, on Android Emulator the `CameraController.startImageStream` returns 15-16 fps which means that while detecting poses with Google Pose Detection or drawing key points on a person's body, I am not getting 30 fps from the camera to even work properly with it.

One approach I am thinking about it doing `CameraController.takePicture` 30 times a second and draw on body points & detect poses using the frames. Additionally, this approach can help us control how many frames we need to capture per second, which we do not control with `CameraController.startImageStream` because it may work too slow or too fast. Would this approach would affect performance badly?

Comment: The number in the ML Kit dev doc was measured on real devices (not emulator). You may want to evaluate it on real devices for performance as well.    Also, there is no official Flutter ML Kit API from Google.  Not exactly sure what additional logic is added in the Flutter plugin developed by external developers. Maybe worth checking with them as well.